# Rails `protect_from_forgery` commented out: security issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf-protection

I'm working on application and I have just discovered that in `ApplicationController` there is a line commented out that looks important.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  # protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  ⋮
```

I got to this point because I was hunting down a stack trace (for an error in production I don't know how to reproduce) that showed me an error in ActionPack:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass)
```

The error is coming from the statement inside this method definition:

```
  def handle_unverified_request
    forgery_protection_strategy.new(self).handle_unverified_request
  end
```

So, my question is two parts:

### 1: Is it a security issue that the csrf line is commented out?

### 2: Is that line being commented out a conceivable reason that this error occurred?

<sub>**versions:**

Ruby (2.2.4p230)

Rails (4.0.13)

ActionPack (4.0.13)</sub>

Comment: for 2: I guess `with: :null_session` sets the strategy called there `forgery_protection_strategy`

Comment: for 1: its indeed super weird the line is commented, there is no good/obvious reason to do so :/ and yes its a security issue

Comment: @apneadiving I'm a rails novice, but without `protect_from_forgery` we just have no CSRF protection at all, right?

Comment: yes you are correct :)